# Why is my floating action button not displaying properly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, floating-action-button

[My floating button image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwGb3.png)

It's a smaller button inside a larger circle, How do I fix this?

layout file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addToKitchenButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_50dp"
    />
```

vector code:

```
  <vector android:height="50dp" android:viewportHeight="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24dp" android:width="50dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying properly"? Please clarify.

Comment: u need to add proper drawable..may be your drawable has black foreground color

Comment: @Mark T please try this ref : https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons

Comment: Not an issue. I think I realised what you missed in previous instructions in your old question. Check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered your previous question so I think I have realised what you missed here. Have a look at this image. You have accidentally added the **Add circle**. Add the selected one with 24dp or 48dp with white color it will work[image: have a look at this image. You have accidentally added the Add circle. Add the selected one with 24dp or 48dp with white color it will work]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SC9F.jpg)

Comment: Oh my god, I cant believe I missed that, lol. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's alright bro. Happens will all. Please do consider upvoting the answer anyway :) and accepting.

Answer (score 0):

**Got Solution For You But I am not recommend it**

> create one vector file for icon color ic_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><vector android:height="40dp" android:viewportHeight="24"
android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="40dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<path android:fillColor="@android:color/black" android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h"/></vector>
```

> create second vector file for same color of float button your ic_add_circle_black_50dp.xml

```
<vector android:height="50dp" android:viewportHeight="24"
android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="50dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

> create layer-list entries let say layer_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_circle" android:top="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:gravity="center"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_50dp"
    android:height="55dp" android:width="55dp"/></layer-list>
```

> Now Modify your FloatButton in xml as

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addToKitchenButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/layer_list" />
```