# Icon not appearing on fab

Tags: java, android

I have a fab(floating action button), here is it's XML code

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/vert"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_circle_black_18dp" />
```

As you can see in the code I want the icon "ic_check_circle_black_18dp" to be on my fab. When I click on "design" I can see the icon on my button, but when I launch my app on my phone (7.1) there are no icons.

I already checked the following questions : 
[AppCompat 23.2 use VectorDrawableCompat with RemoteViews (AppWidget) on API<21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633410/appcompat-23-2-use-vectordrawablecompat-with-remoteviews-appwidget-on-api21)

[Why is my floating action button not displaying its image properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714425/why-is-my-floating-action-button-not-displaying-its-image-properly)

I can't find any solution to my problem

Comment: try using `src` instead of `srcCompat`

Comment: tried android:src, same problem, it's on android studio in the design view, but not in my app

Comment: Also tried with @mipmap same problem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, i avoided the problem by using ImageButton instead of Floating action button and it works.

Comment: What a useless answer! This should certainly not be chosen answer. it's like comparing  "Apples and oranges'!